# How to download android support repository and google repository

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0

I am not getting option of support repository in my SDK Tools as a result i am not able install google repository and android support repository.
Please help
Note: My ide version is 3.6.3 and i want to make a app which involves firebase services in it.

Please help as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support repository is long gone and no longer needed.  You now just add Firebase dependencies as you would any other SDK.  You should [follow the instructions the web site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to get started with Firebase.